# CentOS installation: Anaconda died after receiving signal 7

Tags: 64-bit, centos

I want to install CentOS 6, 64-bit on my PC. I'm getting following error in the first stages of installation (right after media check and before starting graphical installation):

Anaconda died after receiving signal 7!
Here is my system information I gained using CPUZ:

```
CPU: Intel Pentium(R) Dual-core E5700 3GHz, 
Mainboard: Gigabyte P41T-D3, 
Memory: 4GB
```

And Windows 8 System properties says that my processor is x64-based. Is my motherboard x64-based too? I couldn't get to anywhere googling it! Is CentOS error related to this? how can I solve it?

Comment: Which version of CentOS you are using ?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 6.4

Comment: Problem solved. I wrote the ISO image on another DVD and CentOS installed with no problem. Thanks to all and sorry for answering late! I wasn't at work for a while.